# D3.js line chart - can't see line close to the axis

Tags: d3.js

I am having an issue with my d3.js line chart. indeed, the line series can't be seen when the value is close to the axis. you can see the problem on the attached picture.

[image: Screenshot]

here is the code, sorry it is a bit long but I don't really know where the issue could be.

I don't think that the problem is in any css and more in the SVG itself.

```
function realTimeLineChart() {
  // console.log(interval);
  var margin = { top: 50, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 60 },
    width = maxWidth,
    height = 400,
    duration = interval;
  color = d3.schemeCategory10;
  strtime = new Date().getTime();
  var label_table = {
    P: "x",
    E: "y",
  };

  var TimeFormatLive = function (d) {
    //CODE FOR FORMATTING THE X-AXIS LABELS
  };

  function chart(selection) {
    // Based on https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955
    selection.each(function (data) {
      data = ["P", "E"].map(function (c) {
        return {
          label: c,
          values: data.map(function (d) {
            return { time: +d.time, value: d[label_table[c]] };
          }),
        };
      });

      var t = d3.transition().duration(duration).ease(d3.easeLinear),
        x = d3
          .scaleLinear()
          .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]),
        yp = d3
          .scaleLinear()
          .rangeRound([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]),
        ye = d3
          .scaleLinear()
          .rangeRound([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]),
        z = d3.scaleOrdinal(color);

      var xMax = new Date().getTime() - strtime;
      var xMin = xMax - 1 * 60 * 1000;
      x.domain([xMin, xMax]);
      yp.domain([0, MaxP]).nice();
      ye.domain([0, MaxElong]).nice();

      var line = d3
        .line()
        .curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x(function (d) {
          return x(d.time);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
          return yp(d.value);
        });
      var line2 = d3
        .line()
        .curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x(function (d) {
          return x(d.time);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
          return ye(d.value);
        });

      var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

      var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
      let xPixel = width / 2 - margin.top;
      

      gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "axis x");
      gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "axis yp");
      gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "axis ye");
      gEnter
        .append("defs")
        .append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width - margin.left)
        .attr("height", height - margin.top);
      gEnter
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "lines")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .selectAll(".data")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "data");


...

      g.selectAll("g path.data")
        .data(data)
        .style("stroke", function (d) {
          return z(d.label);
        })
        .style("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .on("start", tick);
        })

...

      // For transitions https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1642874
      function tick() {
        //console.log(data);

        d3.select(this)
          .attr("d", function (d) {
            //console.log(d)

            if (d.label == "P") {
              //console.log(d.label)
              return line(d.values);
            } else if (d.label == "E") {
              //console.log(d.label)
              return line2(d.values);
            } 
          })
          .attr("transform", null);

        var xMinLess = new Date(new Date(xMin).getTime() - duration);
        d3.active(this)
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(xMinLess) + ",0)")
          .transition()
          .on("start", tick);
      }
    });
  }

  ....

  return chart;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, finally found my solution after scouting on google for some time!!

the problem was coming from the clipPath that defines where the series can be drawn, and there was a mistake there. I deducted the margin on the right (set at 60) instead of bottom (set at 50) so there was a band of 10px height where no series were shown.

```
  g.select("defs clipPath rect")
    .transition(t)
    .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
    .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom); // here is was -margin.right
```